# My apt is locked after AMD graphics drive update

Tags: apt, amdgpu, lock

Running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS version 5.19.0-41 generic. Installed the latest AMD graphics driver from the AMD site, amdgpu-install_5.4.50405-1_all.deb because I was seeing tearing from my new Radeon RX-6500XT graphics card. Haven't been able to install any programs or updates in my system since then. I can't get past the lock on apt because of the graphics update wanting to install older files over newer files.

I've tried all of the fixes I could find on the internet. There include running:
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt install -f

None of these worked.

After trying all of the above, when I run "sudo apt --fix-broken install", it consistently gives me this:
dad@homedesktop:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
[sudo] password for tang:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu
libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu:i386
Suggested packages:
libglide3 libglide3:i386
Recommended packages:
libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 | libtxc-dxtn0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 | libtxc-dxtn0:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386
2 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 171 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/54.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 177 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 287639 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu_1%3a15.0.50405-1577590.22.04_i3
86.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu:i386 (1:15.0.50405-1577590.22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu_
1%3a15.0.50405-1577590.22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/opt/amdgpu/lib/i386-linux-gnu/llvm-15.0/lib/libLLVM-15.so
', which is also in package libllvm15.0.50403-amdgpu:i386 1:15.0.50403-1538762.2
2.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu_1%3a15.0.50405-1577590.22.04_am
d64.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu:amd64 (1:15.0.50405-1577590.22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu_
1%3a15.0.50405-1577590.22.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/llvm-15.0/lib/libLLVM-15.
so', which is also in package libllvm15.0.50403-amdgpu:amd64 1:15.0.50403-153876
2.22.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu_1%3a15.0.50405-1577590.22.04_i
386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libllvm15.0.50405-amdgpu_1%3a15.0.50405-1577590.22.04_a
md64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Update: Didn't receive any suggestions and could not get past this on my own. Researched it all I could, but it seems to me the AMD driver needs work as it broke my APT. Was not able to update programs while it was locked, could not unlock it. I couldn't do anything with the system and had to reinstall it. I did learn never to trust AMD drive updates after this experience, however. I will not use their driver updates again. Ubuntu drivers seem to work just fine.